# php header Location not working on iframe

Tags: php, iframe, header, location

I've been searching here, and it seems that it's just that it doesn't work. But I had this working perfectly in WAMP Server 2.5, and when I uploaded to actual client's server, it stopped working.
Here's my code:

```
remSoc($_POST['sid'], $db, $_POST['f_baja']);
header("Location: ../files/bSoc.php?e=0&soc=".$_POST['sid']);
```

And its working inside an iframe on the main page. I think I might replace it with some `<script></script>` but does anyone have a clue about why is it working with my test-server and not with remote server? What is the minimum version required for this to work properly?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Use a full path (*`http://www.thewebsite.com/files/bSoc.php?e=.....`*) instead of a relative path(*`../files/bSoc.php?e=.....`*)

Comment: I tried this and got the same result, it doesn't redirect.

Comment: Turn on error reporting (`ini_set('display_errors', 1); error_reporting(-1);`) at the top of your script and debug. Do you get any errors?

Comment: stop using iframes there are much better options

Comment: @Dagon can you tell me some of those options? I used iframes since it's the easiest way to open different pages on the same square.

Comment: @Darren I don't really know how to debug with error display

Comment: Are any errors showing?

Comment: I'm not sure where to search for them, that's my prob